# Would stream=True make me a slow loris attacker if I break inside the loop of r.iter_lines() in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'll scrape a site using this code (which works), but I'm not sure how `requests.get()` handles `stream=True` when a loop is broken with `break`.

This is a minimal working code:

```
import requests
# Not my real target
base_url='https://www.umu.se/?page='
# Real range will be range(1, 250000)
for url in [base_url + str(i) for i in range(1, 3)]:
    chunks = []

    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        for chunk in r.iter_lines(): 
            try:
                if chunk.decode() == '</head>':
                    # Here I parse the data
                    # parse_my_data( ''.join(chunks) )
                    break

                chunks.append(chunk.decode())
            except:
                # This should't happen
```

The reason for all this looping is that I want this to load from server **only** until the end of the `<header>`, thereby saving the hosting server a lot of traffic.

More importantly, I don't want the loop to leave open http-requests. By using `break` in the loop within the `with`-statement, does this script hang up on the remote server forcing the server to network-timeout on each of my request? If so, I have basically scripted something like a slow loris attack, **which I absolutely do not want to**.

Does this script save traffic, and can I run this safely?